# Ruby: Boolean attribute naming convention and use

Tags: ruby, attributes, conventions, boolean-expression

Learning ruby. I'm under the impression that boolean attributes should be named as follows:

```
my_boolean_attribute?
```

However, I get syntax errors when attempting to do the following:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :my_boolean_attribute?

  def initialize
    :my_boolean_attribute? = false
  end
end
```

Apparently ruby is hating the "?". Is this the convention? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*Edit: three-years later; the times, they are a-changin'…*

[Julik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269798/154694) is the simplest and best way to tackle the problem these days:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :dead
  alias_method :dead?, :dead # will pick up the reader method
end
```

My answer to the original question follows, for posterity…

---

The short version:

You can't use a question mark in the name of an instance variable.

The longer version:

Take, for example, `attr_accessor :foo` — it's <del>simply</del> conceptually a bit of syntactic sugar for the following:

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(newfoo)
  @foo = newfoo
end
```

Furthermore, the question-mark suffix is mostly just a convention to indicate that the return value of a method is a boolean.

The best approximation I can make of what you're going for here…

```
class MyClass

  def initialize
    @awesome = true
  end

  def awesome?
    @awesome
  end

end
```

In this case, there may be a case to be made for using `attr_accessor` — after all, it may be explicit that you're working directly with a boolean attribute. Generally, I save the question-mark suffix for when I am implementing a method whose boolean return value is based on slightly more complex conditions than just the value of an attribute.

Cheers!

---

*Edit, two years later, after a recent comment:*

1. Ruby enforces certain naming conventions. <del>Symbols in Ruby can't have question marks. Thus invocations of `:my_boolean_attribute?` both will fail with a `NameError`.</del> Edit: not correct, just use the quoted syntax for a symbol, e.g., `:"my_attribute?"`
2. Symbols are immutable, attempting to assign to one will throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Rubyist usually doesn't use the is_ prefix neither in variable names nor in method names. Just awesome? instead of is_awesome?

Comment: Good point, weppos. Edited out the 'is_' to avoid confusing posterity ;-)

Comment: From this answer I gather there isn't a real convention? :/

Comment: You can do `:"my_boolean_attribute?"`, or even `:"my boolean attribute?"` (good luck calling the latter without `send` though!)

Comment: It's not just syntactic sugar, there's performance gains, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer/5806371#5806371

Comment: To be pedantic about your edit-answer, symbols can have question marks, however variable names (like the instance-var) cannot. See @Julik's answer for what I consider the best way to do this.

Answer (score 43):

The easiest way to quickly add a "question method" is to use aliasing for your reader method

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :dead
  alias_method :dead?, :dead # will pick up the reader method
end
```

Comment: awesome! I was doing it long hand.

Comment: By using this you can use both `dead` and `dead?`, right? But only allows setting through `dead`?

Comment: Setting stays through "dead="

Answer (score 6):

The `attr_accessor` symbol implies that the variable name is `@my_boolean_attribute`, so that's what you should be setting (not the symbol).

Also, you can't use ? for variables, just method names.

Comment: ty for the symbol catch. self.my_boolean_attribute would work correct?

Comment: Oh, let me add-- only within instance methods. In class scope it will look for a class-scope variable (@@my_boolean_attribute). Not that I needed to tell you, of course, but I wanted to make sure what I said was technically correct.

Answer (score 5):

? is convention for methodnames, not variables. You can't use an instance variable named `@foo?`, however you could use a variable named `@foo` and name the (manually created) getter method `foo?` if you wanted to.

Comment: hmm, so the attr_accessor helper won't strip the '?' off the end for me huh. Glad to hear its actually not the convention for instance vars too. Thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Monkey-patching metaprogramming - maybe it can be made more elegant, this is only a quick draft, and I haven't done metaprogramming for a little while...

```
 # inject the convenience method into the definition of the Object class
 class Object
   def Object::bool_attr(attrname)
     class_eval { define_method(attrname.to_s,
          lambda { instance_variable_get('@' + attrname.to_s.chop) }) }
     class_eval { define_method(attrname.to_s.chop+"=",
          lambda { |x| instance_variable_set('@'+attrname.to_s.chop, x) }) }
   end
 end

 ### somewhere later

 class MyClass

   bool_attr :my_boolean_attribute?

   def initialize
     @my_boolean_attribute = true
   end
 end

 # yet even more later

 foo = MyClass.new
 bar = MyClass.new

 foo.my_boolean_attribute = 1
 puts foo.my_boolean_attribute?
 puts bar.my_boolean_attribute?
```

With this approach, you can be DRY and get the nice questionmark too. You just might need to pick a better name than "*bool_attr*", like, "*bool_attr_accessor*" or something similar.

The definitions that I made are a bit cranky, in a sense that the question mark is present in the original symbol. Probably a cleaner approach would be to avoid the questionmark in the symbol name and append it during the definition of the method - should be less confusing.

Oh, and almost forgot to include the obligatory link: [Seeing metaclasses clearly](http://whytheluckystiff.net/articles/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html)

Comment: +1 for the link! Probably won't add the convenience method in this case since its not the convention. I don't want to confuse others. The ideas will be happily cannibalized by other problems though!

Comment: If you are maintaining it in a team, I guess this kind of questions should be discussed indepth at reviews - in some scenarios it might make sense, in some scenarios it won't. I did not code Ruby in a team, so I tend to go for an approach that gives me the least LOC to stare at.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the answers, and while the accepted answer is on-target, it introduces "extra" noise in the class.  The way I'd suggest solving this issue is:

```rb
class Animal
  attr_writer :can_swim
  def initialize(animal_type_name)
    @can_swim = true
    @animal_type_name = animal_type_name
  end


  def can_swim?
    @can_swim
  end

  def to_s
    @animal_type_name
  end
end

dog = Animal.new('Dog in a bag')
dog.can_swim = false
puts "Can this #{dog} Swim? --- [#{dog_without_legs.can_swim? ? 'YEP!' : 'NOPE!'}]"
```