# Creating a Person class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've created a Person class and my code is correct, but I just wanted someone to clarify a specific line.

```
class Person 
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :age

  def initialize (first_name, last_name, age)  
    @first_name = first_name  
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
  end
end
```

The line I'm confused about is the `attr_reader` one. Why does this need to be included and why do I need the `:` before each attribute?

Comment: There is an excellent answer found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer

Comment: You don't know what : before string means? Read about symbol http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

attr_reader is a convenience method that ruby provides for adding the following method in an automated manner(getter methods). I.e. just one line of code will add these three methods in your case.

As for taking a symbol as input arguments, well that is how the method was defined. You can look a bit more at http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader

```
def first_name
  @first_name
end

def age
  @age
end

def last_name
  @last_name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby does not allow public access to instance variable, `attr_reader` is actually a method added to the class Class which gives a easy way to access instance varible.

```
class Class
    def attr_reader(*args)
        *args.each do |arg|
            self.class_eval("def #{arg}; @#{arg}; end")
         end
    end
end
```

`class_eval` above just insert the code in ur class definition and evaluate them ;)