# Getting an object's instance variable

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, accessor

I have an array `s` of `Tile`s with an instance variable `@type`:

```
class Tile
  Types = ["l", "w", "r"]
  def initialize(type)
    @type = type
  end
end
s = []
20.times { s << Tile.new(Tile::Types.sample)}
```

How do I get each `Tile`'s `@type`? How do I return only the objects with a particular `@type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get an array containing each type attribute, you'll first need to create at least a reader for `@type`:

```
class Tile
  attr_reader :type
  Types = ["l", "w", "r"]
  def initialize(type)
    @type = type

  end
end
```

Then use `Array#map` :

```
type_attribute_array = s.map(&:type)
#or, in longer form
type_attribute_array = s.map{|t| t.type)
```

If you want to filter Tile object according to their `@type` value, `Array#select` is your friend :

```
filtered_type_array = s.select{|t| t.type == 'some_value'}
```

Here's the doc for `Array` : [Ruby Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

Comment: @Борис Цейтлин: Here is some additional info on attr_reader that you should consider reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer

Answer (score 0):

you can override `to_s` in your Tile class, return type from it and just iterate over your array `s` to print type by invoking `<tile_object>.to_s`

```
class Tile
  Types = ["l", "w", "r"]
  def initialize(type)
     @type = type
  end

  def to_s
     @type
  end
end

s = []
20.times { s << Tile.new(Tile::Types.sample)}
s.each {|tile| puts tile.to_s}
```