# Rails 2. Calling virtual attribute's setter by update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr, update-attributes, attr-accessor

I have one extra attribute in my form (:pagesize) which is not in database. 
There is also a setter for it:

```
def pagesize= pagesize
  self.preferences["pagesize"] = pagesize
end
```

I want 'update_attributes' method to call that setter.
What is the best type for :pagesize attribute? attr_accessor, attr_writer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that attribute is not defined in your model, you can just define the setter, and then do whichever logic you want:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_writer :pagesize

  def pagesize=(val)
    self.size_of_page = val
  end

end
```

something like this. I wrote the AR version because I assumed you are using it, but the principle is the same for DataMapper or mongoid.

Comment: By the way, I think you can do without attr_writer, provided you don't want to store the value. attr_writer provides you in this case an instance var @pagesize. You can use it only internally and cannot access it from the outside. But this is only worth if you really need the variable. Otherwise the setter method will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

u can call update_attributes on a attr_accessor variable but it needs to be defined as accessible. Also, if u define the variable as attr_writer, u dont need to define a setter method since its added in the backend. Checkout [Why use Ruby's attr_accessor, attr_reader and attr_writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer) for more info