# Access to a non ActiveRecord attribute in before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my view, I use a `<%= f.text_field :latlon %>` to edit the `latlon` attribute (not an ActiveRecord column).  When saving, I want to parse `latlong` and split it into `lat` and `lon` in a `before_save` callback.

I don't know how to access to the params of the `latlon` variable inside the callback.  I have tried `self.latlong` but that calls the same `attr_reader` as the `lat` and `lon` attributes.

I know I can do this in the controller but, this is model logic, no?

```
#app/models/bla.rb
class Bla < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :lat, :lon, :latlon #but latlon is not an ActiveRecord Attribute

  before_save :foo

  def latlon
    "#{lat}, #{lon}"
  end

  attr_writer latlon

  private

  def foo
    self.lat = # regex that parse latlon
    self.lon = # regex that pase coors
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Yes, this is model logic, but you'll need to pass the right value from the controller.

Comment: Its not exactly an error, the problem is that when I call the latlon method (attr_reader) it will return me "#{lat}, #{lon}" , instead of its real value

Comment: can you use @latlon in foo per the answer below?

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr , yes, I pass the right value via form from the view. I mean, If I call latlong without define the latlon method, I will return the right value, but when I enter to the view I will not see the latlon value,

Comment: If the view references an instance of the Bla model, @bla.latlon should contain the current values of `lat` and `lon` formatted correctly.  You might have to handle nil cases or something but that should work fine.  And going the other direction, the form should have `params => {:bla => {:latlon => "12.3456, 78.9012", ...}}` which you should be able to save (see Xathras's and my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that you might replace `attr_writer latlon` with

```
def latlon=(latlon)
  self.lat = # regex that parses lat from latlon
  self.lon = # regex that parses lon from latlon
end
```

And maybe don't make :lat and :lon part of `attr_accessible` since they will never be mass-assigned, i.e. from the `params` array.  `params` passed from the controller will contain the `latlon` value (formatted correctly).

I don't think you need a `before_save` in this case.

Comment: yeah, this is the same as what @Xathras suggested :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can override the assignment method to do what you're describing. This has the bonus of being faster/easier to unit test.

```
def latlon=(new_value)
  # do work to split and assign
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The model should have access to the instance variable `@latlon` that you can use, right?

Comment: yes, but It will call to my latlon method (attr_reader) that will be "#{lat}, #{lon}" , instead of its real value

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer