# Using an instance variable in initialize before defining it

Tags: ruby

I am a Ruby beginner. I am confused by an example from [Why's Poignant Guide](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-5.html).

I understand the following example's use (also from the Poignant Guide) of `picks` in `initialize`, because it is passed in as an argument.

```
class LotteryTicket

  NUMERIC_RANGE = 1..25

  attr_reader :picks, :purchased

  def initialize( *picks )
    if picks.length != 3
      raise ArgumentError, "three numbers must be picked"
    elsif picks.uniq.length != 3
      raise ArgumentError, "the three picks must be different numbers"
    elsif picks.detect { |p| not NUMERIC_RANGE === p }
      raise ArgumentError, "the three picks must be numbers between 1 and 25"
    end
    @picks = picks
    @purchased = Time.now
  end

end
```

But how does `initialize` in the following example start using `picks` without `picks` being passed in as an argument? Here, `note1, note2, note3` is passed in instead. How does that ever get assigned to `picks`?

```
class AnimalLottoTicket

      # A list of valid notes.
      NOTES = [:Ab, :A, :Bb, :B, :C, :Db, :D, :Eb, :E, :F, :Gb, :G]

      # Stores the three picked notes and a purchase date.
      attr_reader :picks, :purchased

      # Creates a new ticket from three chosen notes.  The three notes
      # must be unique notes.
      def initialize( note1, note2, note3 )
        if [note1, note2, note3].uniq!
          raise ArgumentError, "the three picks must be different notes"
        elsif picks.detect { |p| not NOTES.include? p }
          raise ArgumentError, "the three picks must be notes in the chromatic scale."
        end
        @picks = picks
        @purchased = Time.now
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code has an error in it. When I run it in irb I get the following:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `detect' for nil:NilClass
```

There's a discussion [here](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/poignant-stiffs/2005-December/000237.html) from 2005. If you put the following at the beginning of initialize you'll probably get what they were looking for:

```
picks = [note1, note2, note3]
if picks.uniq!
```

Comment: _why gave up on ruby a number of years ago, alas, he's not there to fix things up.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `picks` is not a local variable. It is a method defined by `attr_reader :picks, :purchased`. The method calls the value of the instance variable `@picks`. So `@picks = picks` is the same as `@picks = @picks`, which is assigning its value to itself, which does not have any effect. I think is was written by a person not familiar with Ruby.

Comment: It was written by _why (see link in question)

Comment: :attr_reader :picks defines the AnimalLottoTicket.picks() method for getting the @picks variable in the class and declares @ picks. picks, without an @ is a local variable and not saved between instance methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer

Comment: @PaulRubel No. It doesn't define `AnimalLottoTicket.picks`. It defines `AnimalLottoTicket#picks`, which accesses the instance variable `@picks`. There is no variable declaring in Ruby. If `@picks` is called without assignment, it would be initialized to `nil` at that point. Method definition of `picks` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You're right. I was confused and mistaken. I'd remove my downvote but it won't let me without an edit.

Comment: @sawa Could you briefly explain what you mean by there not being any variable declaring in Ruby? Aren't instance variables and class variables declared variables?

Comment: @mrwnt10 There is no explicit declaration for variable like `int x ...`.