# what does a ruby method ending with an "=" mean?

Tags: ruby

What does a ruby method ending with an "=" mean?

See the available methods in this print out:

```
 2.2.0 :066 > obj.methods(false)
 => [:label=, :label, :description=, :description, :thumbnail=, :thumbnail, :attribution=, :attribution, :license=, :license, :logo=, :logo, :see_also=, :seeAlso=, :see_also, :seeAlso, :related=, :related, :within=, :within, :metadata=, :metadata, :sequences=, :sequences, :structures=, :structures, :viewing_hint=, :viewingHint=, :viewing_hint, :viewingHint, :viewing_direction=, :viewingDirection=, :viewing_direction, :viewingDirection, :service=, :service]
```

For example whats this difference between label= and label?

Comment: Next time consider waiting a little longer before selecting an answer, to allow others who are still preparing their answers to post them before you apply the checkmark. Here you made the selection a mere 20 minutes after posting the question, when only one answer had been given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the methods ending with "=" are setting the instance variable

look at the answer here: [why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer)

Comment: It's important to note that while they *can* set an instance variable, they can also do other things: `def foo=(bar); puts "Not setting the instance variable"; end`

Answer (score 11):

`foo=` is no different than any other method, except:

- it requires precisely one argument and
- Ruby permits you to add spaces before the `=` character.

```
class Foo
  def foo=(other)
    puts 'hi'
  end
end
Foo.new.foo                 = 7
hi

class Goo
  def goo=
    puts 'hi'
  end
end
Goo.new.goo=
```

Ruby says, "I'm waiting for an argument...". So we provide one:

```
4
```

and then she complains about what she asked you to do:

```
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

`=` methods are typically used to create a setter for an instance variable (if `attr_acccessor` or `attr_writer` is not used):

```
class Foo
  def initialize(foo)
    @foo=foo
  end
  # getter
  def foo
    @foo
  end
  # setter
  def foo=(other)
    @foo = other
  end
end

f = Foo.new('dog')
f.foo
  #=> "dog" 
f.foo = 'cat'
  #=> "cat" 
f.foo
  #=> "cat"
```

Comment: very nice answer.  Well described.. I think this answer should be check marked as answered. 1+

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent of setter methods in other languages, it is just convention so it looks more natural to say

```
obj.description="Fun Site"
```

vs

```
obj.setDescription("Fun Site")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about methods that end in `=`

You can see this by running the code below:

```
def bob=
   puts "bob="
end

p send('bob='.to_sym)
```

What is special is the '=' infix operator.  When you write `self.bob = "bill"`. It is interpreted as `self.send('bob='.to_sym, "bill")`.

Putting a `?` at the end of a method is a hint that it returns a boolean (true/false).  Methods that end in `!` hint that the method affects the instance.  See String#chomp vs String#chomp.

You can find out more about ruby operators at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm and more about naming conventions at https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming

Comment: Until recently I thought all methods with names ending in `?` returned booleans, but there are at least two that don't (v2.2): [Numeric#nonzero?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F) and [Float#infinite?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-infinite-3F).