# Ruby: How should I access instance variables inside a class?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object, design-patterns

In ruby you can internally access variables directly via `@var_name` or via private getters `attr_reader :var_name`.

Which solution is more *(semantically?)* correct? Any advantages/disadvantages of using either solution 1 or solution 2?

Solution 1:

```
class Point
 def initialize(x, y)
   @x = x
   @y = y
 end

 def distance
   Math.sqrt(@x ** 2 + @y ** 2)
 end
end
```

Solution 2:

```
class Point
  def initialize(x, y)
   @x = x
   @y = y
  end

  def distance
    Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
  end

private 
  attr_reader :x, :y

end
```

Comment: There are times when you want to use "Solution 3": [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get). Suppose, for example, you wanted to compute the sum of squares of the values of all instance variables. You could write `def sum_of_squares;  instance_variables.reduce(0) { |t,v|  t + instance_variable_get(v) ** 2 };
end`, then `Point.new(3,5).sum_of_squares #=> 34`. [Object#instance_variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) returns an array of the instance variables.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's tricky, I like it! I believe this approach is perfect for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :D

Comment: `attr_reader` is just a shortcut to avoid writing the same, simple and generic getter methods for every attribute. It's part of DRY, imo.

Comment: @c650 it's not "just" a shortcut. It's C extension which is few times faster than writing methods by hand. https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/files/method.h?#annotation=4081781&line=47

Comment: @FilipBartuzi so I've heard. To me, however, if you're using Ruby there's a chance that you don't care about the few extra seconds. Wouldn't you use a different language if you actually cared about speed?

Comment: @c650 Surprise, surprise but people actually do care about efficiency of their Ruby code. you can see community discussing it on [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/sferik/writing-fast-ruby) or [rails conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3gYklsN9uc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the second option:

```
class Point
  def initialize(x, y)
   @x = x
   @y = y
  end

  def distance
    Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
  end

private 

  attr_reader :x, :y    
end
```

For two reasons:

1. `attr_reader` might be [faster](https://web.archive.org/web/20150501215231/https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/files/method.h#annotation=4081781&line=47) (as Filip Bartuzi already pointed out)
2. Using `attr_reader` might make it easier to refactor that class later on by replacing the `attr_reader` with a custom getter method.

Comment: Good solution. I can think of a third reason. Have a look at the comment I left on the question. Another way of doing that is `def sum_of_squares; instance_variables.reduce(0) { |t,sym|  t + send(sym.to_s[1..-1]) ** 2 }; end`, then `Point.new(3,5).sum_of_squares #=> 34`. For each instance variable, this sends the string representation of its getter to the instance to obtain the value of the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader :x, :y` defines the following functions:

```
def x
  @x
end

def y
  @y
end
```

So both methods are equivalent and in fact identical. Performance is also [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer) in both cases, although `attr_reader` can be [faster](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/files/method.h?#annotation=4081781&line=47) than some other variable accessing methods..

Comment: attr_reader is 3x faster than define_method: https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/files/method.h?#annotation=4081781&line=47

Comment: @FilipBartuzi the question is asking about direct access, though, which is not mentioned in the article.