# Is it better practice to use an attr_accessor here or not?

Tags: ruby, oop, instance-variables, attr

I have a class `QuestionList` that stores a list of 'Question' objects.

```
class QuestionList

    attr_accessor :questions

    def initialize
        @questions = []
    end

end
```

I then add questions to the list and then "ask" these questions from my main class as so:

```
list = QuestionList.new
list.questions << Question.new(5, 3)
list.questions << Question.new(1, 5)
list.questions << Question.new(2, 4)

list.questions.each do |question|
    puts "#{question.ask}"
end
```

where `Question.ask` simply outputs the question as a string.

I'm not sure how acceptable it is to be writing to an instance variable from my main class using the `<<` operator, and `list.questions.push(Question.new(5, 3))` is even more unclear from the main class.

Would it be better to have a `QuestionsList.add_question(question)` method?

The same goes for `list.questions.each` - is this acceptable to be used in the main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of `attr_accessor` here is fine, though depending on how much functionality you continue to add, it will likely be clearer to restrict functionality of that class to the class itself.

Regarding your question on using a method within `QuestionList`, this would come down to readability. Something to note first, however: you used `QuestionsList.add_question(question)` as an example. This would create a class method. What you really want here is an instance method, which would read as `list.add_question(question)`, since you already have an instance of the list created. [This blog post](http://culttt.com/2015/06/10/understanding-class-methods-verses-instance-methods-in-ruby/) has some good information on the difference between class and instance methods.

I personally find instance methods would most clearly communicate your intent. I would write out `QuestionList` as follows:

```
class QuestionList

  def initialize
    @questions = []
  end

  def add_question(question)
    @questions << question
  end

  def print_all_questions_in_list
    @questions.each do |question|
      puts "#{question.ask}"
    end
  end

end
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer) has some excellent information on Ruby's `attr` methods, if you'd like additional info there.

Answer (score 1):

The `@questions` array is a private internal implementation detail of your class. It should *never ever* get exposed to clients. There are many reasons for this, two examples are:

- You overpromise an interface: now, all your clients depend on it being an array. What if you later want to change it to something else? A textfile? A database? A webservice?
- You expose operations that break your object invariants: a client can, for example, add an integer to that array. Or `nil`. Or anything else that is not a `Question`.

*How* you store your questions should be an implementation detail. The `QuestionList` should have methods to manage the list of questions. It should probably have an `each` method (and `include Enumerable`), and an `add` method (possibly aliased to `<<`). Maybe also an `[]`, if that makes sense. These methods could simply be delegated to the array, if convenient, but the point is: if you later decide to not use an array, you can do that without anyone even noticing. You can decide to only support those methods you actually *want* to support, as opposed to all ~100 methods of `Array`.