# Extract Custom object from ruby collection

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a custom object, very simple jsut to try and figure out how ruby works.

```
    class SomeObject
  def initialize(name)
    @myName = name
  end

  def sayHello
    puts 'Hello ' + @myName
  end
end
```

I'm then running a search using chef, and creating several of these objects and adding them to a collection : `collection = []` and then `collection << myObject` where myObject is `myObject = SomeObject.new('someName')`

I'm them trying to iterate over this collection, get the object and call sayHello.

```
collection.each do |i|
  p "Something...."
  p i.name #fails
  #i.sayHello # fails

end
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or how I might achieve this?  Thanks.

Edit:  If I print 'i' to the screen I get

## <#::SomeObject:0x00000005546a50 @myName="some-name">

So I'm sure its being created and is in the collection, i jsut can't get the thing out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instance variable is named `@myName` not `@name`, additionally you need to allow your instance variable to be read publicly using the [`attr_reader`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer) directive:

```
class SomeObject
  attr_reader :myName

  def initialize(name)
    @myName = name
  end

  def sayHello
    puts 'Hello ' + @myName
  end
end

collection = [ SomeObject.new('Hunter') ]
collection.each do |i|
  puts i.myName # output= Hunter
  i.sayHello()  # output= Hello Hunter
end
```

Comment: LEGEND!  Thanks! :D