# Using Devise in different controller: undefined method "resource="

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Devise 4.2.1 and Rails 5.0.1. I'm trying to use Devise `sign_in` in a controller other than `registrations`. There were a bunch of methods that weren't defined, so I had to add them as helpers:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
    # ^the source of the error^
  end

  def resource_class
    devise_mapping.to
  end
end
```

But now I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Static#show
undefined method 'resource=' for (class)
```

I don't have "resource=" written anywhere in my code, certainly not on the line the error points to (marked above). **Where is my server getting that error from?**

---

Also, I think I'm just using the standard sign_in code:

```
<%
build_resource({})
set_minimum_password_length
yield resource if block_given?
respond_with self.resource
%>

<% form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  ...
```

Comment: What's the reason for you to move the `sign_in` method from outside it's default place?

Comment: @LeonardoPrado I'm trying to build a sign_in partial that I can render anywhere on my app.

Comment: What is inside Static#show method and in static/show.html.erb?

Comment: @JoeMorano You can use whatever partial you want, and place it wherever you want, but still have it route through the registrations controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your question has 2 answers: Why this error is happening, and how to have a `sign_in` partial to use on all your controllers:

## Creating the `sign_in` partial

First of all, the `sign_in` method belongs to `sessions`, not `registrations` be careful to not replace the wrong controller :)

And you just added a few more code than needed for what you want. To create a partial sign_in to use anywhere, just use the default Devise form in it:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>

  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <% end -%>

  <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
<% end %>
```

That part with `build_resource({})` isn't needed, as it'll be handled by Devise itself when you submit the form. And since `build_resource` isn't needed, you just need the following code on your ApplicationHelper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

This should be enough to have a sign_in form in any controller view. If you need more control over the login flow, you can check the **Configuring Controller** section on [Devise Readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) for more information on how to create a customizable controller.

## Why your code throws a NoMethodError error

Your code throws an NoMethodError because you haven't defined a setter for the `@resource` instance variable. It should be either:

```
def resource=(value)
  @resource = value
end
```

or with `attr_writer :resource`

I recommend this question for more info on the topic:
[Why use Ruby's attr_accessor, attr_reader and attr_writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer)

Comment: As for me. When I added resource setter then application didn't recognise that. It treated that as normal local variable. Solution that works for me it is simply assignment `@resource = user`