# Ruby: class passes methods of running object

Tags: ruby, sinatra, helper

I have a class where I create a new instance variable called @client which is an object in itself. Now, in another file I create an object from this class, but cannot access the methods of the @client object. How do I do?

example:

```
class A_Helper
    def initialize
        @client = Module::Client.new('info')
        p @client
        # <Module::Client:0x000000017fd018>
    end
end
---------------------------
class A_Controller
    @A_Helper = A_Helper.new
    p @A_Helper.client
    # <class:A_Controller>: undefined method `client' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: added an example which might help

Comment: Still can't reproduce _that_ error. Given the code you've shown, `@A_Helper` can't be nil.

Answer (score 1):

you have declared a local variable `@client`, which his accessible only inside your class. If you want to get access from outside, you need to declare getter or shortcuts like `attr_accessor`/`attr_reader` (check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer) ).

```
class A_Helper
  attr_reader :client

  def initialize
    @client = Module::Client.new('info')
  end
end
```

Comment: It gets access to the object, but i still cant do A_helper.client.Method(), as it says "undefined method `client' for nil:NilClass" edit: sorry, didnt make it clear in the example im trying to call methods in client